# Could someone tell me why this piece of code doesn't call me that function?

Tags: javascript, html

In practice I don't know why the `lengthselector1` and `lengthselector2` doesn't call my `length()` function
Furthermore invert button don't call my function `length()` only `invert()` function
And I don't know because only `lengthinput` calls `length()` function

Could anyone help me with this code? It all seems right to me.

```js
function length() {
  var lengthinput = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthinput').value);
  var oper = document.getElementById('lengthselector1').value;
  var oper2 = document.getElementById('lengthselector2').value;

  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'm') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 1000 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'd') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 10000 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'c') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 100000 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'mi') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 1000000 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'mic') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 1.0000E+9 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'de') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 100 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'h') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 10 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'me') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput / 1000 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'g') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput / 1000000 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'z') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput / 1.0000E+18 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'i') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 39370.0787 || 0;
  }
  if (oper === 'k' && oper2 === 'a') {
    document.getElementById('lengthresult').value = lengthinput * 1.0000E+13 || 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tbn2">
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="lengthinput" oninput="length()" /> <br/><br/> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="lengthresult" readonly /><br><br> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="lengthselector1" onchange="length()">
        <option selected value="k">Kilometre</option>
        <option value="m">Metre</option>
        <option value="d">Decimetre</option>
        <option value="c">Centimetre</option>
        <option value="mi">Millimetre</option>
        <option value="mic">Micron</option>
        <option value="de">Dekametre</option>
        <option value="h">Hectometre</option>
        <option value="me">Megametre</option>
        <option value="g">Gigametre</option>
        <option value="z">Zettametre</option>
        <option value="i">Inch</option>
        <option value="a">Angstrom</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td> <button onclick="invert(); length()">Invert</button> </td>
    <td>
      <select id="lengthselector2" onchange="length()">
        <option value="k">Kilometre</option>
        <option selected value="m">Metre</option>
        <option value="d">Decimetre</option>
        <option value="c">Centimetre</option>
        <option value="mi">Millimetre</option>
        <option value="mic">Micron</option>
        <option value="de">Dekametre</option>
        <option value="h">Hectometre</option>
        <option value="me">Megametre</option>
        <option value="g">Gigametre</option>
        <option value="z">Zettametre</option>
        <option value="i">Inch</option>
        <option value="a">Angstrom</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're getting an error. Always keep your developer console open. I'm pretty sure the problem is the name of your function. If you change the name of the function to something more particular, *or* if you assign event handlers outside of your HTML (which is better for many reasons anyway), you can get around that problem.

Comment: What do you mean? the name of the function I'm calling is right, 
and also how do I open the developer console in web ?

Comment: The problem has to do with the way "onchange" etc event handlers work. It's complicated to explain, but common names like "length" will cause problems. If you call it "computeLength()" or something, you won't get that error.

Comment: A ok, a little strange but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code works if you call your function something else than `length`. This is surely a reserved word of some kind, it's very generic. IT's probably being overriden by something. If you call your function, say, `calculateLength()`, it works.

However, you must notice that this coding style is extremely tedious and inefficient (manually checking one by one every single combination). Since you have 12 units times 12 units, you'll have to duplicate your code 144 times (!!) which is a red flag in coding.

A more efficient way would be to have a mapping object, then it's 4 lines of code :

```js
const $oper1 = document.getElementById('lengthselector1'); // cache your elements
const $oper2 = document.getElementById('lengthselector2');
const $result = document.getElementById('lengthresult');
const $lengthInput = document.getElementById('lengthinput');

const unitsMappings = {
  k: {
    k: 1,
    m: 1000,
    d: 10000,
    c: 100000,
    mi: 1000000,
    mic: 1.0000E+9,
    de: 100,
    h: 10,
    me: 1/1000,
    g: 1/1000000,
    z: 1/1.0000E+18,
    i: 39370.0787,
    a: 1.0000E+13
  }
}

function calculateLength() {
  const lengthinput = parseFloat($lengthInput.value),
        oper1 = $oper1.value,
        oper2 = $oper2.value;
  $result.value = lengthinput * unitsMappings[oper1][oper2] || 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbn2">
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="lengthinput" oninput="calculateLength()" /> <br/><br/> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="lengthresult" readonly /><br><br> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="lengthselector1" onchange="calculateLength()">
        <option selected value="k">Kilometre</option>
        <option value="m">Metre</option>
        <option value="d">Decimetre</option>
        <option value="c">Centimetre</option>
        <option value="mi">Millimetre</option>
        <option value="mic">Micron</option>
        <option value="de">Dekametre</option>
        <option value="h">Hectometre</option>
        <option value="me">Megametre</option>
        <option value="g">Gigametre</option>
        <option value="z">Zettametre</option>
        <option value="i">Inch</option>
        <option value="a">Angstrom</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td> <button onclick="invert(); calculateLength()">Invert</button> </td>
    <td>
      <select id="lengthselector2" onchange="calculateLength()">
        <option value="k">Kilometre</option>
        <option selected value="m">Metre</option>
        <option value="d">Decimetre</option>
        <option value="c">Centimetre</option>
        <option value="mi">Millimetre</option>
        <option value="mic">Micron</option>
        <option value="de">Dekametre</option>
        <option value="h">Hectometre</option>
        <option value="me">Megametre</option>
        <option value="g">Gigametre</option>
        <option value="z">Zettametre</option>
        <option value="i">Inch</option>
        <option value="a">Angstrom</option>
      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "onfoo" event handler functions are built such that there are scope layers (basically like `with` statements) implicitly around the code. So it's not like a reserved word, it's that "length" resolves to something that shadows the global identifier. One of the better reasons not to use "onfoo" event handler binding :)

Comment: I really thank you, I didn't think about this :D

Comment: Well, to tell the truth, this part of the code doesn't help me ... It is faster but where there are divisions / it doesn't work, in practice this code just does * not also /

Comment: Well, `m` to `Km` would be `0.001`, job done. You are surely aware than dividing by 1000 is the same thing as multiplying by 0.001. I have corrected my ratios, now this code works with all units (Gigametre, Zettametre  etc). See, that's the point of not duplicating your code 144 times: when you need to change something, you change it once.